# Sublime don't want to find words with only a few letter match

Tags: sublimetext3, sublimetext2, sublimetext

So, somehow - when I'm trying to search something - I need to fully write this word otherwise sublime will not find it.
Check screen:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ecw6L.png)
Is that a new feature or that's a bug , or some kinda of setting which I need to disable somewhere? But that's so annoying
(version 3.2.2)

I tried to find it, but not results. Also I reinstalled the sublime - still this thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have the "Whole Word" option selected in the Find Panel. It is the toggle button with a graphic of two quotes on it. Disabling that will allow you to search for partial words.

Reinstalling Sublime doesn't affect your user data/preferences/session etc. so it is expected that it made no difference.